# How to fix TypeError: this._url is undefined in ArcGIS JS API (Query)

Tags: javascript, widget, arcgis-js-api

I'm tasked with developing a custom widget for ArcGIS' Web App Builder and i've been trying to get a Query to work using the ArcGIS Javascript API 3.28 so i can build a report using layer information. But upon attempting to test the query by means of a button, i get a TypeError: this._url is undefined.

```
define(['dojo/_base/declare', 'jimu/BaseWidget',
        'jimu/dijit/Report', 'esri/layers/FeatureLayer',
        'jimu/dijit/PageUtils', 'dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin', 'esri/tasks/IdentifyTask',
        'esri/tasks/IdentifyParameters', 'esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol', 'esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol',
        'esri/graphic', 'esri/Color', 'dojo/_base/lang',
        'dojo/_base/html', 'dojo/on', 'dojo/domReady!',
        'esri/tasks/QueryTask', 'esri/tasks/query'],

function(declare, BaseWidget, Report, FeatureLayer,
        PageUtils, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, IdentifyTask, IdentifyParameters,
        SimpleFillSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol, Graphic,
        Color, lang, on, Query, QueryTaskTest) {

  var baseWidgetClass = declare([BaseWidget], {
    baseClass: 'jimu-widget-demo',

    postCreate: function() { // POST CREATE!
      this.inherited(arguments);
      this.map.infoWindow.hide();
    },

    startup: function() {
      this.inherited(arguments);
      console.log('startup');
    },

    onClose: function(){
      console.log('onClose');
    },

    _onBtnPrintClicked: function(){
    console.log("Begin query test");
    var queryUrl = "https://webportalurl/arcgis/rest/services/ServiceName/MapServer/0";
    var queryTask = new QueryTaskTest(queryUrl);
    var query = new Query();
    query.returnGeometry = false;
    query.outFields = ["*"];
    query.where = "HAB_IPTU = 2089358";
    console.log("Running execute");

    queryTask.execute(query).then(function(results){
      console.log(results.features[0]);
    });
  }

  });
  return baseWidgetClass;
});
```

Comment: No, the error you are getting is because at the point you are calling new QueryTask, QueryTask is no constructor like. You have either overwritten it somewhere else, or, possibly, you are using another framework that is doing dependency injection. Try creating a QueryTask and some other objects above your return statement. Add an unrelated constructor like "esri/Color" and use var b = new Color("blue") just to see if it's your code or your configuration.

Comment: I created the Color as suggested and it returned no errors.

Comment: Though declaring QueryTask outside the return statement still returns the not a constructor error.

Comment: ok, we are getting somewhere now. So that means that the QueryTask is either overwritten somewhere or defined as something else somewhere else in your code. I would call it something else Like QueryTastTest in your function like this function(declare, BaseWidget...etc..QueryTaskTest).

Comment: Also, can you log the value of QueryTask above the return statement like console.log(QueryTask) and paste the output here?

Comment: Changing function(...., QueryTask) to function(... QueryTaskTest) returns a "QueryTask is not defined" error as expected.

Comment: yes but you would need to change the instantiation as well  var queryTask = new QueryTaskTest(queryUrl);

Comment: Creating an instance of QueryTaskTest above the return statement (declare([BaseWidget]) returns the "not a constructor" error for QueryTaskTest.

Comment: something is overwriting QueryTask. Can you get QueryTask to work in a simplified version and post it in a codepen? You can see that it works in the pen that I posted so it's got to eb some other part of your application that's messing it up.

Comment: here it is in a pastebin:
https://pastebin.com/saCL537H
Having to omit the service url for security purposes. If you could edit out of your codepen, i'd appreciate it

Comment: The problem is the arguments are out of order starting at 'dojo/_base/html'. 'dojo/_base/lang', matches up with lang in the function but then 'dojo/_base/html' matches up with the on, 'dojo/on' matches up with Query and finally 'dojo/domReady!' matches up with QueryTaskTest. use the modules that don't require a corresponding constructor at the end of the define list otherwise you have to include them in the function definition to preserve the order.

Comment: This solved my problem! Thank you! now onto IdentifyTask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the QueryTask or how you are calling it. The arguments in the define statement and function definition do not match up.

'dojo/_base/lang', matches up with lang in the function but then 'dojo/_base/html' matches up with the on, 'dojo/on' matches up with Query and finally 'dojo/domReady!' matches up with QueryTaskTest. use the modules that don't require a corresponding constructor at the end of the define list otherwise you have to include them in the function definition to preserve the order.

like this

```
    define(['dojo/_base/declare',
        'jimu/BaseWidget',        
        'jimu/dijit/Report', 
        'esri/layers/FeatureLayer',
        'jimu/dijit/PageUtils',
        'dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin',
        'esri/tasks/IdentifyTask',
        'esri/tasks/IdentifyParameters', 
        'esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol', 
        'esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol',
        'esri/graphic', 
        'esri/Color', 
        'dojo/_base/lang',
        'dojo/on',        
        'esri/tasks/query',
        'esri/tasks/QueryTask',
        'dojo/_base/html', //these last two are at the end
        'dojo/domReady!'], //because they don't need to be called or instantiated directly.

    function(declare, 
        BaseWidget, 
        Report, 
        FeatureLayer,
        PageUtils, 
        _WidgetsInTemplateMixin,
        IdentifyTask,
        IdentifyParameters,
        SimpleFillSymbol,
        SimpleLineSymbol,
        Graphic,
        Color,
        lang,
        on,
        Query,
        QueryTaskTest) { ....});
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. Will be more careful of the declarations in the future!

Answer (score 2):

QueryTask on api 3.28 expects the url as *String* : https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/querytask-amd.html#querytask1

Try this :

`var queryTask = new QueryTask(queryUrl);`

or

`var queryTask = new QueryTask("MapServerUrl");`

Comment: Doing that returns a TypeError;
"TypeError: QueryTask is not a constructor"